# MySQL Fetch Multidimensional array

Tags: mysql

I just wondering can I do the this multidimensional data in mysql? I always using concat or store procedure, but is it possible to do this using the simple select? Thank you for your answer.

```
select username, (select firstname, surname from tblprofile) as tblprofile
from tbluser;

tbluser = array {
    username => User001,
    tblprofile => array {
        firstname => John,
        surname => Smith
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Nested subqueries (or CTEs) each with its own GROUP BY.

Comment: But why would you? Application code is better suited to this task